# ¿Cómo recoger los valores de select MULTIPLE en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Tengo en un form un SELECT con el atributo MULTIPLE, y necesito traer los valores a Javascript.

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Con .value solo trae el primer valor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La propiedad indicada para estos casos es [selectedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions).

> Contiene una lista de los elementos `<option>` contenidos dentro del elemento `<select>` que están actualmente seleccionados.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const el = document.getElementById("cars");
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let seleccionados = document.getElementById('cars').selectedOptions;      
      for(let i = 0;  i < seleccionados.length; i++){
          console.log(seleccionados[i].value);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A no olvidar que la documentación es siempre una buena amiga :)

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto, donde recorremos los option del select y si está seleccionado lo mostramos en consola:

```js
function muestraSeleccion() {
  select = document.getElementById('cars');
  for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    o = select.options[i];
    if (o.selected == true) {
      console.log(o.value)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button id="muestra_seleccion" onclick="muestraSeleccion()">Ver selección en consola</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

También he encontrado esta solución usando el [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) y [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
function ejecutar(){
    const el = document.getElementById("cars");
    const seleccionados = [...el.selectedOptions].map(o=>o.value);
}
document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener('click', ejecutar, false);
```

HTML:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Pero no sé si esto es mejor